# Are derivatives of the $N(0, 1)$ bounded and Proof the formula

Tags: real-analysis, probability, derivatives, normal-distribution, hermite-polynomials

Suppose that $\varphi$ is the density of the standard Gaussian distribution given by
$$
\phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb R$. The derivatives of $\varphi$ are given by the formula
$$
\phi^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n\mathit{H}_n(x)\phi(x)
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\ge0$, where $\mathit{H}_n$ is the $n$-th Hermite polynomial:
$$
H_n(x) = (-1)^n \exp(x^2/2) \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} \exp(-x^2/2).
$$

## Question

・I want to show that $\phi^{(n)}$ are the $n$-th derivative of $\phi$.

**edit:** I could show by mathematical induction.

・I want to show that all the derivatives $\phi^{(n)}$ are bounded function of $x$.

**How can these be shown?**

Comment: The limit is zero as $|x|\to\infty$, so when you cut off the tails you have a continuous map in a closed interval.

Comment: @AlvinL thank you. I understand the theorem you mentioned. So why does $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} \phi ^{(k)}(x) = 0$ hold for any $k$?

Comment: It's essentially a product of exponential map and a polynomial. What is $\lim p(x)e^{-x^2}$ as $|x|\to \infty$, where $p(x)$ is any polynomial?

Comment: Does this mean that $e^{-x^2}$ is stronger than p(x) as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, because $|p(x)e^{-x^2}| \leqslant |x^Me^{-x^2}|$ for sufficiently large $M$ as $|x|\to\infty$ and the RHS goes to zero by applying L'Hopital an appropriate number of times.